# Python string.replace() not replacing specified character string

Tags: python, arrays, string, replace

I have a dataframe that contains a field "Search_Term". Some of the search terms contain the "AND" operator which I would like to remove, e.g.

```
df_concat.Search_Term.unique()
```

returns:

```
Out[38]: array(['alcohol illness', 'alcohol fatality', 'alcohol cirrhosis', 'alcohol death',
       'alcohol poison', 'alcohol AND illness', 'alcohol AND cirrhosis'],
      dtype=object)
```

So I try to remove them using string.replace():

```
df_concat["Search_Term"] = df_concat["Search_Term"].replace(" AND ", " ")

df_concat.Search_Term.unique()
```

But I still get:

```
Out[39]: array(['alcohol illness', 'alcohol fatality', 'alcohol cirrhosis', 'alcohol death',
       'alcohol poison', 'alcohol AND illness', 'alcohol AND cirrhosis'],
      dtype=object)
```

Why is string.replace() not functioning as I expect it to in this case? I've had a look through previous questions but none of the ones I've read seem to offer a solution in this case.

Comment: Can you try this and let me know the result `df_concat["Search_Term"] = df_concat["Search_Term"].astype(str).replace(" AND ", " ")`  or `df_concat["Search_Term"] = df_concat["Search_Term"].str.replace(" AND ", " ")`

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

As Preetham suggested above I needed to convert to string first (i.e. use .str.replace() rather than just .replace())

```
df_concat["Search_Term"] = df_concat["Search_Term"].str.replace(" AND ", " ")

df_concat.Search_Term.unique()
```

gives:

```
Out[38]: array(['alcohol illness', 'alcohol fatality', 'alcohol cirrhosis', 'alcohol death', 'alcohol poison'],
      dtype=object)
```